# Unrotate final path of path that has multiple translates and rotations

Tags: wpf, xaml, svg, transform

I'm working in WPF, but SVG would probably be the same so I've tagged it. I have some paths that I am rotating/translating multiple times and in it's final rendered position, I would like to take the path and "unrotate" at that position. The issue is that I can't find the right CenterX/CenterY for this (renderTransformOrigin="0.5, 0.5" doesn't work because the final rendered path has been translated). Finding the boundingbox of the final rendered shape also doesn't not work to rotate it back.

Here's what the non-rotated paths look like:
[image: non-rotated shapes]

And here's what they look like when rotated:
[image: rotated shapes]

To get this, here's my XAML.

```
<Canvas>
            <Rectangle Fill="DarkGray" Opacity=".3"  Canvas.Left="168.48"  Width="100.08" Height="200.16" Canvas.Top="164.88"/>
            <!-- ////////////////// -->

            <!-- ///shape/// -->
            <Path Stroke="Purple" x:Name="purpleShape" Data="M0,150 25,150 25,0 75,0 75,150 100,150 50,200 Z" StrokeThickness="2">
                <Path.RenderTransform >
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <!--shape transforms-->
                        <RotateTransform Angle="30" CenterX="50" CenterY="100"/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="46.08" Y="0"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Path.RenderTransform>
            </Path>

            <!-- ///childGroup/// -->
            <!-- ///childGroup.shape/// -->
            <Path Stroke="Green" x:Name="greenShape" Data="M0,25 150,25 150,0 200,50 150,100 150,75 0,75 Z" StrokeThickness="2">
                <Path.RenderTransform >
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <!--shape transforms-->
                        <RotateTransform Angle="330" CenterX="100" CenterY="50"/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="50" Y="200" />
                        <!--childgroup transforms-->
                        <RotateTransform Angle="60" CenterX="150" CenterY="150"/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="96.46" />
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Path.RenderTransform>
            </Path>
            <!-- ///childGroup.shape/// -->
            <Path Stroke="Red" x:Name="redShape" Data="M0,150 25,150 25,0 75,0 75,150 100,150 50,200 Z " StrokeThickness="2">
                <Path.RenderTransform >
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <!--shape transforms-->
                        <RotateTransform Angle="330" CenterX="50" CenterY="100"/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="150" Y="0" />
                        <!--childgroup transforms-->
                        <RotateTransform Angle="60" CenterX="150" CenterY="150"/>
                        <TranslateTransform X="0" Y="96.46"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Path.RenderTransform>
            </Path>
         </Canvas>
```

Notice in this code `<Rectangle Fill="DarkGray" ....` as the first element. This is where I am hoping to "unrotate" the **red path** to, so that it fits in this bounding box (the size of this is the size of the non-rotated bounding box).

Here's what this looks like:

[image: target position identified]

The final render path of the **red shape** is: `Data="M150,283.064 171.651,295.564 246.651,165.66 289.952,190.66 214.952,320.564 236.603,333.064 168.301,351.365 Z "` and now I want to unrotate that (-30 degrees) so that it is pointing down again - again, at this same exact location. (again, getting the bounding box of the red shape doesn't work as it has a different center x/y than I need in order to unrotate).

So using another shape (orange shape) and the path data above, I place it on the red shape and try to rotate it back (i.e. so it doesn't appear rotated).

```
                <Path RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Stroke="Orange" x:Name="unrotatedShape" Data="M150,283.064 171.651,295.564 246.651,165.66 289.952,190.66 214.952,320.564 236.603,333.064 168.301,351.365 Z " StrokeThickness="4">
                <Path.RenderTransform >
                    <TransformGroup>
                        <RotateTransform Angle="-30" CenterX="0.5" CenterY="0.5"/>
                    </TransformGroup>
                </Path.RenderTransform>
            </Path>
```

And this is the result:

[image: result]

This is obviously getting rotated from the path as it is both rotated and translated (e.g.  `Data="M150,283.064...`). It's that 150,283.064 that are causing the issue.

***So I'm asking for solutions that allow me to "unrotate" the "red shape"*** (the rendering of which is the "orange shape") at the same position so that it looks like the following (**blue shape**).

[image: desired]

Comment: Maybe you don't want to set the Path's RenderTransform in the first place, but instead set the `Transform` property of the Geometry in its Data.

Comment: @Clemens thanks for the response. Do you mean create this all in code? I've tried this as welll and get the same results? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Caveat

Your grey rectangle is not the same size as the red arrow. I'll place the center of the red arrow on the center of the grey box.

## Setup

Rotating around some point, `P`, is equivalent to translating `P` to the origin, rotating around the origin, and then translating the origin back to `P` again.

Define a function which does that, and check how it modifies the individual coordinates. (Below is Mathematica.)

```
In[1] :=
RotateVAroundP[V_, \[Theta]_, Px_, Py_] := {{Cos[\[Theta]], -Sin[\[Theta]]}, {Sin[\[Theta]], Cos[\[Theta]]}} . (V - {{Px}, {Py}}) + {{Px}, {Py}}
MatrixForm[Simplify[RotateVAroundP[{{x}, {y}}, \[Theta], Px, Py]]]

Out[2]//MatrixForm =
MatrixForm[{{Px + (-Px + x)*Cos[\[Theta]] + (Py - y)*Sin[\[Theta]]}, {Py + (-Py + y)*Cos[\[Theta]] + (-Px + x)*Sin[\[Theta]]}}]
```

[image: Setup]

## Testing

Rotate the point `(1,0)`, `90` degrees around the point `(1,1)` to `(2,1)`.

```
In[3] :=
MatrixForm[RotateVAroundP[{{1}, {0}}, 90*Degree, 1, 1]]

Out[3]//MatrixForm =
MatrixForm[{{2}, {1}}]
```

[image: Test]

## Solving

Start with the center of the original red arrow: `V1 = (50, 100)`. Apply all the transformations. The final transformation has the desired `-30` degrees, around an unknown point `(x,y)`. This final rotation needs to place the center of the arrow on the center of the box, which is `(168.48 + 100.08/2, 164.88 + 200.16/2)`.

```
In[5] :=
V1 = {{50}, {100}}; 
V2 = RotateVAroundP[V1, 330*Degree, 50, 100]; 
V3 = V2 + {{150}, {0}}; 
V4 = RotateVAroundP[V3, 60*Degree, 150, 150]; 
V5 = FullSimplify[V4 + {{0}, {96.46}}]; 
Solve[RotateVAroundP[V5, -30*Degree, x, y] == {{168.48 + 100.08/2}, {164.88 + 200.16/2}}]

Out[10] =
{{x -> 218.78146997001204, y -> 264.4524797111341}}
```

[image: Solve]

## Verifying

I don't know anything about WPF, but I dabble in SVG. Working from the initial opaque arrow to the transparent one, the subsequent transformations in each element are applied from right to left.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="https://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="-25 -25 350 425" width="560" height="680">
    <rect xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" stroke="black" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="375"/>
    <rect fill="darkgray" fill-opacity=".3" x="168.48" width="100.08" height="200.16" y="164.88"/>
    <path stroke="red" id="redShape" d="M0,150 25,150 25,0 75,0 75,150 100,150 50,200 Z " stroke-width="2" fill=" red"/>
    <use href="#redShape" transform="rotate(330, 50, 100)" fill-opacity=".8"/>
    <use href="#redShape" transform="translate(150,0) rotate(330, 50, 100)" fill-opacity=".6"/>
    <use href="#redShape" transform="rotate(60,150,150) translate(150,0) rotate(330, 50, 100)" fill-opacity=".4"/>
    <use href="#redShape" transform="translate(0,96.46) rotate(60,150,150) translate(150,0) rotate(330, 50, 100)" fill-opacity=".2"/>
    <use href="#redShape" transform="rotate(-30, 218.781, 264.452) translate(0,96.46) rotate(60,150,150) translate(150,0) rotate(330, 50, 100)" fill-opacity="0"/>
</svg>
```

[image: Verify]

## Generalizing

If you want to rotate the point `V` to the point `W` by applying a rotation `θ` around a point `P`, the coordinates for `P` are the expressions below.

```
In[11] := 
FullSimplify[Solve[RotateVAroundP[{{Vx}, {Vy}}, \[Theta], Px, Py] == {{Wx}, {Wy}}, {Px, Py}]]

Out[11] =
{{Px -> (1/2)*(Vx + Wx + (Vy - Wy)*Cot[\[Theta]/2]), Py -> (1/2)*(Vy + Wy + (-Vx + Wx)*Cot[\[Theta]/2])}}
```

[image: Generalized]

Comment: If you were to solve this manually, since you had the *render* path for the last arrow, you wouldn't need to do all the calculations to turn `V1` into `V5`. You could compute `V5`, the center of your last render, directly from that path. That would make the expression easier to solve - you wouldn't have to calculate `In[5]` through `In[9]`, your only hand calculations would be `In[10]`.

Comment: Thank you! I find that I can get this to work using your method of using the starting cx/cy. I tested it on the `greenShape` as well and it works. However, when I use my rendered path, it doesn't work for `V5`. The cx/cy of that is different  - the rendered geometry is `M 150,283.062 L 171.650,295.562 246.650,165.658 289.951,190.658 214.951,320.562 236.602,333.062 168.301,351.363 150,283.062 Z`, so that puts the bounding box at `X: 150, Y: 165.658, Width: 139.951, Height: 185.705`, which makes it's `CX: 219.975` and `CY: 258.511`, which is different from your `CX: 218.781, CY: 264.452`

Comment: @Meihua You were right when you said you don't want the bounding box. Use the actual corners of the arrow to compute `(cx, cy)`. The back corners are `(246.650, 165.658)` and `(289.951, 190.658)`. The midpoint of the back is `(268.3005, 178.1580)`. The tip is `(168.301, 351.363)` and so the center of this path (assuming the symmetry of the original) is the average of those two: `(218.30075, 264.7605)`.

Comment: Welcome! Suppose you don't know `θ` or `P` for the rotation. Then you need 2 points before and after the rotation. You do `In[10]` twice with a variable `θ` in the place of `-30 Degree`. This gives 4 equations (for the 4 coords before, mapping to the 4 coords after) in 3 variables (`θ`, `Px`, `Py`). Because your point coords are rounded these 4 equations don't have an exact solution. There are several ways to resolve this, one being just use 3 of the 4 equations. Then solve a second set of the 3 to check your answers are within roundoff. If not, no rotation will map the 2 points.

Comment: is this a question you might be able to answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73860873/reversing-the-flip-and-rotation-of-an-image-fill-in-a-path-that-is-flipped-and-r